# Compiling Visual Studio C++ code in Mingw32

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, mingw32

I am attempting to compile the .cpp file from [this](https://github.com/carterjones/hello-world-dll/tree/master) Github repo, using mingw32.  In particular, I can compile .cpp file containing the code:

```
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
DWORD WINAPI MessageBoxThread(LPVOID lpParam) {
  MessageBox(NULL, "Hello world!", "Hello World!", NULL);
  return 0;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
                      DWORD ul_reason_for_call,
                      LPVOID lpReserved) {
  switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
      CreateThread(NULL, NULL, MessageBoxThread, NULL, NULL, NULL);
      break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
      break;
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

using mingw32-g++ and the command:

`i686-w64-mingw32-g++ hello-world.cpp -o hello-world.dll -shared`

And it compiles with out errors. When I attempt to run the dll, using `rundll32.exe hello-world.dll,MessageBoxThread`, it doesn't work Even though the export function does exist (visible using 'dllexp.exe').  When I take the same code, via the solution in Visual Studio and compile it, the resulting dll binary works as intended.

Why does the above code not produce the same desired functionality using mingw32-g++ as it does for Visual Studio and how can I modify the above source code to compile with mingw32-g++?

Comment: "it doesn't work" Please be more specific.

Comment: `CreateThread` is a function that's unsafe to call with loader lock held (inside `DllMain`).

Comment: Usually you can't link code compiled with different compilers.

Comment: You do not have to make `DllMain` exported. Also I'm not sure about calling `MessageBoxThread` from the rundll32. Your function requires one argument while rundll32 provides no arguments to the function.

Comment: What does `dumpbin /exports hello-world.dll` return? (must be run from the VS Command Prompt)

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Sorry, I didn't want to state the obvious.  "It doesn't work" refers to the MessageBox popping after the `rundll32.exe hello-world.dll,MessageBoxThread` code.

Comment: @JesperJuhl  Which is why folks (like me) swallow their pride and ask questions to folks like you that can help guide us.

Comment: @BenVoigt Correct, I am learning about how DLL functions and the concept of a loader lock is new to me.  I have found great material on the problems with calling WIN API functions from DLLMain and can appreciate the methodology behind it.  For now I'm just looking for an easier way to compile C++ code without having to use Visual Studio.

Comment: Nothing is obvious. If you get any error messages, show them. If you don't get any, state that as well.

Comment: You don't have to use Visual Studio, the Microsoft compiler works just fine from the command line.